# Is there a cross platform command that will print something to console?

Tags: java, linux, windows, unix, cross-platform

I am writing an "end-to-end" test for a method that takes in command, runs it, and returns the stdout output in a string. It looks something like this:

> public static String runCommand(String ... command) { }

What I need is a cross-platform command that writes something to the console as we have a mix of windows/linux machines and I need the test to run everywhere. I'd prefer not to have an `if (os == 'windows')` type statement.

I don't want `System.out.println(command)` here, I want to execute the code and get the output.

For instance, `sleep 5` will sleep for 5 seconds on both Unix/Linux and Windows but won't output anything. `echo hello` won't work on Windows because `echo` is a command from Unix's Terminal.

Any ideas?

I am not looking for comments on the "testability" of this code.

Comment: Simple answer: No. Bit more elaborated: yes, but not out of the box. You could run Cygwin.

Comment: Improvement on old exec API: `ProcessBuilder`, capture: `System.setOut(InputStream) / setErr / setIn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hostname`, `ping`, `route`, `whoami`, `help`, ... ?

Comment: Now you need to run those commands from a Java-code. This doesn't help the OP in any way.

Comment: @Charlie - actually this was EXACTLY what I was after. Upvoted and accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @MCND - just an FYI, hostname works perfectly...however `whoami` doesn't.

Comment: @Cheetah, i only have a stripped down, virtualized, headless, debian at hand for testing, and it worked for me. It is good to know it still includes things that are not present everywhere (linux). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> ...`echo` hello won't work on Windows because echo is a command from Unix's Terminal

Just out of interest: Is this still true?

I seem to be able to run `echo test` from a Windows cmd prompt just fine *(Windows7x64)* and [Wikipedia also seems to suggest `echo` being available on Windows platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(command)). Also some [Windows server documentation is listing `echo` as a command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo). I'm using it for the exact same purpose as the original author, to test subprocess execution and stdout values. *(From Python though)*

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Runtime` for this:

```
public static String runCommand(String command) throws IOException {
    String output="";

    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); // Execute the command
    InputStream is=p.getInputStream(); // Get InputStream

    byte[] buf=new byte[1024]; // Increase if you expect output above 1024 characters
    is.read(buf); // Read the input and write to buf
    output=new String(buf).trim(); // Remove the empty bytes at the end

    return output;
}
```

If you also want to read any errors, add the following code:

```
    InputStream es=p.getErrorStream();

    byte[] ebuf=new byte[1024];
    es.read(buf);
    if(new String(ebuf).trim().length()!=0) { // If errors occured
        output+="\n Errors: "+new String(ebuf).trim();
    }
```

Let me know whether it works or not
Happy coding :) -Charlie